# Can't decode csv file using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This is the code and `encoding='utf-8'` is also not working:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sunil.csv',encoding ="utf-8")
print(df)
```

And here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/utube/sunil.py", line 2, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv('sunil.csv',encoding ="utf-8")
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 685, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 542, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 764, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: I'm not sure we can debug this. I'm gonna guess that the encoding is `cp1252`. Then I'm all out of suggestions because _we can't see the file_

Comment: @alollz we got a wager on this? :P

Comment: If i use latin-1
  `data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 881, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 896, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 937, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2132, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 15, saw 5`

Comment: Great, so im half-way to winning my bet. (We're still probably not gonna be able to fix this ) but did you try cp1252? Im unsure why you skipped my suggestion first; i havent just made that encoding up

Comment: @roganjosh i got this error
 `File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 15, in decode

    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 68: character maps to <undefined>`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try ISO-8859-1 as it worked for me when I had same issue

dataset = pd.read_csv(r'filename.csv',encoding = "ISO-8859-1")